# What are good ways to scan a sheet of negatives?

Tags: 35mm, scanning

I have several binders filled with PrintFile 35mm negative holders and sheets of contact prints. Unfortunately, not all of the negative sheets have been scanned. I can put them on a flat bed scanner and then try to clean up the scan with photoshop, but it doesn't look good. My flatbed Epson scanner can scan two strips of negatives at a time, but not 6. Is there an easy way to scan the whole page at once?

The pages of negatives look like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're just using them as reference then you could put each sheet on a light table, cover with glass to flatten, and take a picture. Reverse (and color balance) in photoshop and print.

Comment: That’s a great idea. Thanks. Now I need to buy another cheap light box.

Comment: Yep. You can get them on Amazon [for very little](https://www.amazon.com/Portable-LITENERGY-Artcraft-Sketching-Animation/dp/B07F147VF6/), but no guarantees on color temp. or how even the light distribution would be...

Comment: Thanks. I don't care much about color balance.

Answer (score 0):

Epson flatbeds, like the V550, are set up for reflective light, which is what you want for scanning paper. For negatives, they use a light in the lid to backlight the negatives, since reflective light from a negative produces a dark, muddy image with no detail.

The light in the lid is only wide enough to backlight two 35mm strips. It will not accommodate six strips at a time.

Comment: This is not an answer; it is simply restating what OP had already mentioned. Furthermore, the more advanced flatbed models like the V850 have a much larger scanning area for transparencies.